# Edit/Remove CLI System Notice

Tags: linux, linux-mint, terminal, login

I'm wondering how I can change the default system message that shows when on the CLI from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. By default it shows the message

```
Welcome to <name>
  * Documentation: <url>
```

I was wondering how I can change or remove that? I would of thought it be changeable with the `/etc/issue`, `/etc/issue.net` or `/etc/motd` files but they don't have those lines anywhere in their files, and are for SSH logins, I just want to be able to change what the system displays when I login to CLI when I switch to it from a desktop environment. This is clearly system default message, not related to SSH, but something else.

in my case here I'm using Linux Mint 17.

```
Welcome to Linux Mint
 * Documentation:  http://www.linuxmint.com
```

any ideas to which file this default message is set in?

Comment: It will likely be one of the files in `/etc`. Try `find /etc/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -H "Welcome to Linux Mint" {} + 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: I tried that command there but it didn't return anything. There was no output.

Answer (score 0):

Another user posted a similar problem on the Linux Mint forum: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=28403&p=164776.

Apparently, Linux Mint 17 rewrites `/etc/issue`, `/etc/motd`, etc on reboots.

To prevent this, edit `/etc/linuxmint/mintSystem.conf`:

```
[global]
enabled = True
[restore]
lsb-release = True
etc-issue = False
splash-screens = True
ctrl-alt-backspace = True
update-grub = True
```